Can the lens from an MLX90614-DCI sensor be transferred to other MLX90614 models to limit the FOV?
After discovering my misconception about the temperature range of the MLX90614-DCI version—which is actually -70°C to 270°C rather than the -70°C to 380°C I initially believed—I decided to switch to the MLX90614-DCA version. The DCA version does cover the desired temperature range of -70°C to 380°C, but it has a Field of View (FOV) of 90°, which is too wide for my project.
Interestingly, I noticed that the DCI version’s datasheet doesn’t clearly specify this narrower temperature range, which led to some initial confusion.
My question is: has anyone tried removing the lens from the DCI version and installing it onto another MLX90614 sensor, such as the DCA, to limit the FOV? If so, how did it work out? Are there any potential issues or considerations I should be aware of regarding compatibility, sensor performance, or physical attachment?
Any insights or experiences with modifying the MLX90614 sensor’s lens would be greatly appreciated.

I didn't study the datasheet, but you're saying the version without the silicon lens is sensitive to higher temperatures?  Is the reason for that that silicon absorbs shorter wavelength radiation emitted by hotter objects and thus prevents measuring their temperature?
